# Mongo PlanExecutor error during aggregation for 5 million keys

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm currently doing an aggreate on my collection which examines around 5 million keys, and the collection contains an `id` field (which is not unique), and a `payload` object containing `ts` which is a timestamp.

The query, in which I'm trying to find the most recent timestamp for each unique ID, is:

```
item.get_collection().aggregate([
                {"$match": {"id": {"$in": [1, 2, 3...]}}},
                {"$group": {"_id": "$id", "ts": {"$max": "$payload.ts"}}}
            ]):
```

However, sometimes this throws an `PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: query plan killed :: index 'last_ts_index' dropped` exception.
This is the index I have defined `[('id', pymongo.ASCENDING), ('payload.ts', pymongo.DESCENDING)]`.

Is there anything I can do to optimize the query, or to add an index so that it doesn't raise an exception?

Comment: Well a simple solution is probably to stop dropping the `last_ts_index` index while the query is running. Do you know why it is being dropped?

Comment: Also, I think you may be able to rewrite your query to use $first (after a $sort) to take advantage of the [$group optimization](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#indexes) to improve performance altogether

Comment: I have no idea, can it be that the index is dropped after the exception is raised?

Comment: You have cause and effect backwards. The exception is being raised _because_ something (else) is dropping the index while the query is running. The `mongod` logs would have info about which client is issuing the `drop` command

Comment: The really weird part of this is that the error shows up only at 2 AM CET, even though the same command/aggregation runs every 5 minutes.

Comment: I'm not sure that's really weird. In fact I'd say it's perfectly consistent with the hypothesis above. Namely it seems there is nothing in the code you're looking at that is problematic which is why it can (and usually does) run successfully. There seems to be some daily task happening that interferes with the job. Is there some sort of data refresh or something along those lines that runs at that time? In any case, like was mentioned before, the log file will contain information about the source of the `drop`